# save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'student'?

Tags: django, many-to-many

There is m2m relationship

models.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=249)


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=249)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, through='Connect')

   
class Connect(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
class CreateStudent(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/admin/'
    redirect_field_name = 'index'
    template_name = 'app/create_student.html'
    model = Student
    fields = ('name',)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        for student in form.cleaned_data['name']:
            connect = Connect()
            connect.student = self.object
            connect.course__name = 'math'
            connect.save()
        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

how to do what when creating a `Student` instance the default value was automatically added `Course` instance

And how create in view method to define default `Group`

p r

Answer (score 1):

You first need to save the object to the database, furthermore using `course__name` will *not* work, you have to retrieve the primary key:

```
class CreateStudent(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    # …
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        for student in form.cleaned_data['name']:
            connect = Connect()
            connect.student = self.object
            connect.course = Course.objects.get(name='math')
            connect.save()
        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot if it not difficult have a look to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68102420/how-to-create-specific-view.  this will help me a lot